# Using SVG icons with jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm using a jQuery toggle for a show/hide button. Is there a way to incorporate SVG icons (in this case, Octicons)?

```
$(function () {
        $('.show-button').click(function(){
            $(this).text(function(i,old){
                return old=='Show less' ?  'Show more {% octicon chevron-down height:25 class:"right left" aria-label:toggle %}' : 'Show less';
            });
        });
    });
```

Right now, this outputs:

`[ Show more <svg height="25" class="octicon octicon-chevron-down right left" aria-label="toggle"...]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Consider using [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead.

Additionally, I do not know what your base element is, but having svg's inside buttons or inputs might not be ideal. So you might want to use a button-looking span if you want to adhere to the standards.

Comment: Thank you so much (for the answer and the standards tip)!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it!

`$(function () {
        $('.show-button').click(function(){
            $(this).html(function(i,old){
                return old=='Show less' ?  'Show more {% octicon chevron-down height:25 class:"right left" aria-label:toggle %}' : 'Show less';
            });
        });
    });`